# Are my GPIO ports not working?

Tags: gpio, measuring

On my Raspberry Pi, I tried to do some experiments with GPIO, without success.

Measuring the voltage between GND and GPIO11, for example, always helds a result of 0. I am using /sys/class/gpio commands to turn GPIO on and off. Between GND and 3.3V, it returns 2.2V. Te only one that seems to work is between GND and 5v.

EDIT

- Turned on the raspberry py
- Plugged in a flat cable between raspberry and a breadboard
- Measured P1-25 (GND) and P1-01 (3v3). Got 2.2 V
- Followed there instructions (https://sites.google.com/site/semilleroadt/raspberry-pi-tutorials/gpio). GPIO pin 11 didn't change voltage

Any clues?

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you told us what you have actually done you may get some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you followed the instructions, this should work.
**I suspect that you have your cable crossed over**. 
You say `Measured P1-25 (GND) and P1-01 (3v3). Got 2.2 V` This is wrong, I suspect that you are actually measuring between pin 2 (5v) and pin 26.

I suggest you install `WiringPi` (mentioned in the instructions). This is much easier to use, and more importantly includes a utility `gpio readall` which displays the state of all the pins.

Get your instructions right (as shown in the `gpio readall` utility) then you can work out if you have a wiring problem. NOTE this works even if nothing is connected.

Comment: You saved my life! My cable was indeed crossed over. There was an arrow on the cable that was supposed to point at P1 on Raspberry.